# why i can not debug sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder

Tags: java

i want to debug code `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename));`
when i breakpoint , i can not enter source code

```
    /**
 * Creates an InputStreamReader that uses the default charset.
 *
 * @param  in   An InputStream
 */
public InputStreamReader(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
    try {
        sd = StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(in, this, (String)null); // ## check lock object
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // The default encoding should always be available
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

i have attachment and download many version source code also.
who can help me , thanks.

Comment: Did the source code you attached include the code for sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder ? Where did you get that code ?

Comment: Can you add some more information? What exactly are you doing and what is happening? It's not really clear from your question, at least to me.

Comment: my source code contain sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder, i download it from network, i forget download from where

Comment: you mean my source code version is not right?

Comment: more question ?  Question is i can not enter this code:

Comment: sd = StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(in, this, (String)null); // ## check lock object